# Whole Program in CASE

Tags: embedded-systems

I'm going to start by saying, this may not be the correct place to post this.

So...I'm working in Embedded Development, using C.

Is there any benefit or disadvantages to doing the following:

```
while (1)
{
   i++;
   switch (i)
   {
      case 1:
         x_get_inputs();
         break;
      case 2:
         x_react();
         break;
      case 3:
         x_set_outputs();
         i = 0;
         break;
      default:
         break;
    }
}
```

Rather than a standard list of function calls?

I think this is similar to a *Round Robin RTOS*?

My logic is that the program cycle time will be shorter, and as such this should be more efficient?

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly for the two options? How do they differ? What optimization level are you compiling with (some functions can be inlined)?

Comment: Nope, I normally just use -o

Comment: If you are using gcc or something that has similar command line options, look at the output with -S (and varying levels of -O).  You'll find a '.s' file in the directory instead of object files.

Comment: I'm not back in the office until Monday, theoretically....what do you think?

Comment: Unless shown otherwise, the additional work to maintain such code would add more time and likelihood of error than function calls.  With proper optimizations, those function calls are likely inlined. Write code that clearly shows what you intend to do so the next person doesn't say bad things about you.

Comment: You should not be worrying about the efficiency of a function call yet. Write idiomatic, sensible code first, then measure for optimization only after a problem is identified.

Answer (score 5):

Assumed the variable `i` is initialized to 0 at the beginning, your code is just an obfuscated version of

```
while(1)
{
    x_get_inputs();
    x_react();
    x_set_outputs();
}
```

(and it took me some minutes to understand that your code really has this semantics, and no hidden emulated `goto`). That's shorter and showing explicit what's going on here. Your original version is hard to understand, hard to maintain, and I guess it will be not even bring you any advantages at the assembly or performance level. So for this case, I would advice against it.

On the other hand, when this is really called in a context where `i` can have an arbitrary value from 0 to 2 beforehand, the construct makes more sense (though I think there should be at least a safety guard around this preventing i beeing >2, which would end in an endless loop without calling any of the three functions any more.

However, IMHO the construct is still overly complicated even for that case. Here is a shorter version, which does the same:

```
while (1)
{
   switch (i)
   {
      case 0:
         x_get_inputs();
      case 1:
         x_react();
      case 2:
         x_set_outputs();
      default:
         i = 0;
    }
}
```

You can make this even more clean by replacing the integer `i` by an enum (with well choosen names), and change the name of `i` to something like "firstOperation". Furthermore, one should add some kind of safeguard for the i>2 case as well. I leave this as "an exercise for the reader".

Comment: It depends on the context, you haven't really seen where i comes from. 

If it is say parameter of a function call, one of the 3 function calls above might not be called. (ie what if 'i' starts with a value 1 or 2, etc..). I think the semantic is different, and I can see what he wants to drive us here. Nice try.

Comment: @randomA: I agree, seem my edit.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your post, there is a problem when i > 3 not 2. The new construct you have is nicer than the original.

Comment: @randomA: you are right, but it is in fact unclear what shall happen in the i>3 case. Changed my posting accordingly.